# How to test Generators in Python 3. It gives error all the time

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, generator, python-unittest

I have snippet of the code below. Which I cannot change but I need to test. What it does is it connects to the server and gets data that I need. In particular I need to insert falsely input for variable data1 on line 12 to test it.
But I can't achieve it so far.

```
1. url = "http://localhost:8000"
2. data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
3.
4. def get_data():
5.     yield data.read()
6.
7. #generator
8. def get_objects(in_stream):
9.     json_object = ""
10.    buffer = b''
11.    for data1 in in_stream:
12.        data = buffer + data1
13.        data = data.decode("utf-8")
...

22.for json_dict in get_objects(get_data()):
23.   print(repr(json_dict))
```

`get_object(in_stream)` must be some sort of iterable, right? So, I am trying to pass a string there:

```
def test_falsely(self):
    self.assertEqual(solution.get_objects("bla bla"), "blabla")
```

But I am getting an error:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_falsely (__main__.TestStringMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in test_falsely
    self.assertEqual(solution.get_objects("bla bla"), "blabla")
AssertionError: <generator object get_objects at 0x103433308> != 'blabla'
```

---

What do I do wrong? Does anybody have idea how to test it? Thank you.

Comment: Well, `get_objects` doesn't return or yield anything, so this isn't a [mcve]. Having said that, you need to join the generator you get back from `get_objects`.

Comment: it yields down the code. I put ellipsis to identify that I cut some code out. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a *generator* can't be equal to a string.

When your call your function: `get_objects("anything")`, it *returns a generator object* you can iterate over to get the values.

If you want to check if the `i`th element returned is equal to `something`, do:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(get_objects("bla bla")):
    if i == 3:
        return self.assertEqual(elem, something)
```

Comment: @Cooper, you can always accept it if it solved your issue

Comment: I am trying to test your solution, but encountered another problem with input now and trying to solve it. I will come back for sure. So far, when I pass bytes into `get_objects(b'bla bla')` I somehow get an integer inside when I try to iterate (Line #11 above). The error occurs at line #13 and it says that `int has no attribute .decode`.